# How to get parameter in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, get, request, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('users*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{!! route('users.index', 2016) !!}">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> YEAR 2016
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{!! route('users.index', 2017) !!}">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> YEAR 2017
    </a>
</li>
```

When I hover over the link to the year 2016, the url will be like this :

`localhost/mysystem/public/users?2016`

My routes\web.php is like this :

```
Route::get('users/index?{year}', 'UserController');

Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

And my controller user is like this :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $year = $request->input('year');
    echo $year;die()
}
```

There is exist error like this :

```
UnexpectedValueException in Route.php line 646: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\UserController]
```

Is there any people who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should be as:

```
Route::get('users/index/{year}', 'UserController@index')->name('users.index.year');
```

Your controller as:

```
public function index(Request $request, $year)
{
    echo $year;die()
}
```

Then you can use it in your view as:

```
{{ route('users.index.year', ['year' => 2016]) }}
```

Comment: There exist error like this : `ErrorException in UserController.php line 36: Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::index()`

Comment: Try to comment out your resource line `Route::resource('users', 'UserController');` and try it again, maybe it is causing some problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have not changed the view. now, it is already working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameter in route like this:

```
Route::get('users/index/{year}', 'UserController@index');
```

View:

```
<a href="{!! route('users.index', ['year' => 2016]) !!}">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> YEAR 2016
</a>
```

Controller (get as argument inside controller method):

```
public function index($year)
{
    echo $year;
    die();
}
```

Or - If you want to pass a parameter as GET params to routes just do this:

```
Route::get('users/index', 'UserController');
```

and inside your `<a href="">`:

```
<a href="{!! route('users.index', ['year' => 2016]) !!}">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> YEAR 2016
</a>
```

> The statement: `{!! route('users.index', ['year' => 2016]) !!}` will create a route like this: `http://website.com/users/index?year=2016`

and grab it in controller using `request()` helper like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $year = request()->get('year');
    echo $year;
    die();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems I need your help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788737/why-the-deleted-data-still-appear-in-the-interface

Answer (score 0):

You will get it from method arguement

```
public function index(Request $request,$para_year)
{
    $year = para_year;
    echo $year;die()
}
```

and you route should be

```
Route::get('users/index/{year}', 'UserController@index');
```