# Why the deleted data still appear in the interface?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.3

Look here :

[image]

When I click button delete, data deleted still appear in the interface.

I look at the table in the database, the data is erased.

Data can be lost if I run this: `php artisan cache:clear` on git bash.

How without running the command, data can be erased?

**UPDATE**

My controller is like this :

```
public function deleteAccount(Request $request)
{
    $id_account = $request->input('id_account');
    try{
        if($this->user_service->deleteAccount($id_account)) {
            $status='success';
        }else {
            $status = 'failed';
        }
        return redirect('member/profile/setting/account')->with('status',$status);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return $this->respondInternalError();
    }
}
```

My service is like this :

```
public function deleteAccount($id_account)
{
    return $this->user_bank_repository->delete($id_account);
}
```

My repository is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Models\UsersBank;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\EloquentRepository;
class UserBankRepository extends EloquentRepository
{
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {

        $this->setContainer($container)
             ->setModel(UsersBank::class)
             ->setRepositoryId('rinvex.repository.uniqueid');
    }
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $data = self::find($id)->delete();
        return $data;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is server time issue, be sure about it is set properly.

Comment: @Rishi, How can I set it? I use localhost. I use laravel 5.3

Comment: You need to show us the code that gets run when you click the delete

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I update my question

Comment: You need to call the view once the row is deleted, so that the page gets refreshed with the current state of the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I had try it. It's the same. Look my question again. I had update it

Comment: Once page is reloaded, data still apears on the page?

Comment: @kapil.dev, Yes. The data no update. But in table on the database, the data updated

Answer (score 0):

I see you are also using the rinvex repository. I don't see your code about fetch data. I assume you are fetching data from the repository cache. In your repository, your delete function.

```
public function delete($id){
    return $this->delete($id);
}
```

this should clear the repository cache.
if you would like clear the cache of the repository manually, try the following in your repository method.

```
$this->forgetCache();
```

or

```
$this->getContainer('events')->fire($this->getRepositoryId() . '.entity.updated', [$this, $modelInstance]);
```

actually forgetCache() method shall do, I'm using it in my repository after I made mass update to my table.